# do something extraordinary for only a particular value of jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I want change inner html and class when user slide into a specific value. let's say we have slider `with max:101,` value. Now when user slide into 101, user will get a alert box or a prompt or get some text changed. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/zbu47nos/2/) and snippet:

```js
 $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            min: 1,
            range: false,
            step: .01,
            max: 101,
            value: 1,
            animate:"slow",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $(".value").text("slider value: " + Math.round(ui.value));
                
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.slider-holder {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.value {
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slider-holder">
      <div id="slider"></div>
      <a class="value">slider value: 1</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it seems like you could just test for when `ui.value === 101`:

```js
 $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            min: 1,
            range: false,
            step: .01,
            max: 101,
            value: 1,
            animate:"slow",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $(".value").text("slider value: " + Math.round(ui.value));
                if (Math.round(ui.value) === 101) {
                    alert('something extraordinary!')
                } 
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.slider-holder {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.value {
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slider-holder">
      <div id="slider"></div>
      <a class="value">slider value: 1</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Friend for your help.

Comment: can i just get ab string instead a number value like 101?

Comment: the result should be like slider value: ab

Comment: What is `ab`? And No, the `value` of the slider will always be a number. You could reference an array: `var myArray = []; myArray[101] = "ab"; $(".value").text(myArray[ui.value]);`